# Chrono duration<double> crashes

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I've read a few question about "how to convert `duration` to `double`"
And i know it is used something like this

```
  high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();
  high_resolution_clock::time_point end = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<std::intmax_t> t =
      duration_cast<duration<std::intmax_t>>(end - start);
  auto temp = std::chrono::duration<double>(t).count();
```

But for some reason it crashes for me.

[image: Error message]

Is there different kind of chrono used nowayday?
I'm using visual studio 19 with `default` language standart.

Comment: [Your code doesn't crash](https://godbolt.org/z/ro7q7r) in MSVC on godbolt on the latest compiler at least.  Please provide a [mcve] so we know that your problem is in the code you posted.

Comment: The NTSTATUS associated with the exception (`STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`) suggests that detailed compiler flags may be helpful as information added to your question.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Godbolt doesn't seem to be able to compile binaries in MSVC (so it we couldn't see a crash).

Comment: I compiled the example given by @Yakk-AdamNevraumont locally using Visual Studio 2019, no crash (release x86).  The version of Visual C++ is `16.8.3`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ah my bad.

Comment: presumably your code is attempting to use an instruction not supported by your processor, please provide a [mre] with full compiler settings and your CPU and the full visual studio version

Comment: The illegal instruction is caused by code not shown and not related to chrono.  Search for "0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction" for clues on how to fix it.

Comment: Such a search would be completely fruitless. This is either UB elsewhere in the program, or a compiler bug.